# Vaadin, Jetty: Runnable jar - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory$Acceptor

Tags: maven, vaadin, jetty-9

I want to build and start runnable jar for Vaadin Jetty project.
Here my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <name>BSA</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <vaadin.version>13.0.1</vaadin.version>
        <jetty.version>9.4.14.v20181114</jetty.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.21</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository needed for the prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>localrepository</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Repository needed for the prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.14.v20181114</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mvysny.karibudsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>karibu-dsl-v10</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0.v20130308</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.myproject.AppStarter</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode can be activated with either property or profile
                mvn clean package -Pproduction-mode
                mvn jetty:run-exploded -Pproduction-mode
            -->
            <id>production-mode</id>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-production-files</goal>
                                    <goal>package-for-production</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.myproject.AppStarter</mainClass>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                                </manifest>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Class-Path>config/</Class-Path>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I create runnable (standalone) jar like this:

```
mvn verify
```

Maven generate **shaded** jar:  `myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar`

Nice.

Them I copy jar to separate folder I try to start jar like this:

```
java  -jar myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
```

But I get error:

```
INFO: Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
Mar 18, 2019 1:29:22 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver newCometSupport
WARNING: Failed to create AsyncSupport class: class org.atmosphere.container.JettyServlet30AsyncSupportWithWebSocket, error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Mar 18, 2019 1:29:22 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver newCometSupport
SEVERE: Real error: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at org.atmosphere.container.JettyServlet30AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.<init>(JettyServlet30AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:237)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:308)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:294)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:2092)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:914)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:838)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.initAtmosphere(PushRequestHandler.java:218)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.initAtmosphereForVaadinServlet(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:184)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.init(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:149)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.contextInitialized(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners.contextInitialized(ServletContextListeners.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:957)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:922)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.myproject.AppStarter.run(AppStarter.kt:89)
    at  com.myproject.AppStarterKt.main(AppStarter.kt:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more

Mar 18, 2019 1:29:22 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver resolveMultipleNativeSupportConflict
WARNING: Found multiple containers, please specify which one to use: org.atmosphere.container.Jetty7CometSupport, org.atmosphere.container.Jetty7CometSupport,  until you do, Atmosphere will use:class org.atmosphere.container.Jetty7CometSupport
Mar 18, 2019 1:29:22 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
```

In my code `AppStarter` I try to start server:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler

      val server = Server(port)
        server.handler = handlers
        server.start() // error here
        server.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be the atmosphere not detecting the new Jetty version websocket support and trying to use the old server specific implementation.

You can for the JSR356 by adding a init parameter:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.asyncSupport</param-name>
   <param-value>org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Or in annotation:

```
@WebInitParam (
   name = org.atmosphere.cpr.asyncSupport,
   value = org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport
)
```

Comment: Where I need to set <init-param>? Inside what node?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, added the params under ../WEB-INF/web.xml for the expanded web app, but nothing ...
Using latest jetty 9.4.20 and vaadin 14.0.5

Similar issue
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/7948577/atmosphere-framework-error

Answer (score 0):

org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory$Acceptor is part of Jetty 8 or below

Either upgrade to new Jetty 9 WebSocket API or degrade your libraries to jetty 8